# How to use lambda function with dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How can I use lambda function with map for create a object? I receive 1 or more objects in my serializer by Json, then I want iterate this json and create a object. Here is my code from `models.py`, and my `serializers.py`.

```
# Models.py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def insert_car(self, i, user):
        car = i.get('car')
        item = i.get('item')
        quantity = i.get('quantity')

        ModelA.objects.create(user=user, car=car, item=item, quantity=quantity, status=self.STATUS_PENDING)
        return True

# serializers.py
class ModelASerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['car', 'item', 'quantity']


class MultipleOrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    items = ModelASerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['items']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        list = self.data.get('items')
        user = self.context.get('request').user
        a = map(lambda i : ModelA.insert_car(i, user), list)
        return self.data
```

I tryed print anything inside my `insert_car`, but doesn't print nothing, the method `insert_car` doesn't called

**#Update01**

According to @bro-grammer, "In python 3 map is a lazy iterator. It doesnot do anything util you consume it. Try surrounding map(...) with list(map(...))"

then, the line calling map function looks like this:
`create_car = list(map(lambda i : ModelA.insert_car(i, user), list))`

Comment: I think your `create` method signature should be like `def create(self, validated_data)`

Comment: What’s the difference? Can you explain to me??

Comment: It only accepts two arguments one is `self` and other is `validated_data`. In your signature you are passing several different arguments.

Comment: Because that the lambda map doesn’t work? If a use a for inside my insert_car its works normally. I don’t understand why lambda doesn’t work.

Comment: Oh i get it now. In python 3 map is a lazy iterator. It doesnot do anything util you consume it. Try surrounding `map(...)` with `list(map(...))`

Comment: hmmm, nice, it's works. I used `create_car = list(map(lambda i : ModelA.insert_car(i, user), list))`. Thanks a lot my friend @bro-grammer